# Pass parameter which contains "$" to ParameterizedRemoteTrigger plugin?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-groovy

As title, if the parameter contains "$", it doesn't work. Escaping with "" also doesn't work.

```
            remote_param='TASK_ENV_VARS=\$test'

            def handle = 'org.jenkinsci.plugins.ParameterizedRemoteTrigger.pipeline.RemoteBuildPipelineStep'(
                    remoteJenkinsUrl: REMOTE_JENKINS_URL,
                    job: REMOTE_JOB,
                    blockBuildUntilComplete: true,
                    auth: CredentialsAuth(credentials: jenkinsCredentialID),
                    abortTriggeredJob: true,
                    parameters:remote_param,
                    useCrumbCache: true, useJobInfoCache: true, maxConn: 1, pollInterval: 10
            )
```

It throws error:

```
ERROR: Remote build failed with 'IOException' for the following reason: 'org.jenkinsci.plugins.tokenmacro.MacroEvaluationException: Unrecognized macro 'test' in 'TASK_ENV_VARS=$test''.
```

if the parameter doesn't contain "$", it runs well.

Answer (score 0):

You can escape a dollar sign with another dollar sign in this case.

```
triggerRemoteJob remoteJenkinsName: 'remote.jenkins.org', job: 'build-remote',
  parameters: """FOO=$BAR
BUILD_ARGS=$params.EXTRA_ARGS """ + ' --build-arg USER=$${LOGIN} --build-arg PASSWORD=$${PWD}'
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. However, what I want is to pass the exact content of a parameter which contains character "$" to downstream. The content is not a variable. For example: a description content is: this is a $any string. 
I tried to add double $ in that param but it seems not working.